# Xcode NSMangedObjectContext save causing crash

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, save, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Since upgrading my iOS app to Xcode 6.3 (and I admit, doing a few changes to the code), I'm getting a crash on a save to my app's managedObjectContext.

Within Xcode, I get a break on the *save* call without any information in the debug window. The instruction pointer shows an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

However, the call-stack shows this 'worrying' information..

[image]

Instruments is not helping me. On the device the app crashes without interception. The device logs show similar debug info...

> Date/Time:           2015-04-13 11:39:53.861 +0100 Launch Time:
>   2015-04-13 11:39:32.805 +0100 OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
>   Report Version:      105
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000001bd5bec8 Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libobjc.A.dylib                  0x0000000197ba8174
>   objc_release + 20 1   libobjc.A.dylib
>     0x0000000197ba9720 (anonymous
>   namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 560 2
>   liboainject.dylib                 0x0000000100a657dc 0x100a60000 + 22492
>   3   CoreFoundation                    0x00000001865c5070
>   _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24 4   Foundation                     0x0000000187504ff8 -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 148 5   CoreData
>     0x00000001863ab6a4 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue
>   _processReferenceQueue:] + 2092 6   CoreData                          0x00000001863b323c
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 4704 7   CoreData                         0x00000001863b1790 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 160

As you can see, I am saving the data on a viewWillDisappear of my ViewController.

```
-(void)saveCompanyDetails
{
    // Do change to my 'Company' NSManagedObject
    ...

    // Save the Moc
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    __autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;

    if( ![managedObjectContext save:&error] )  // CRASH HERE
    {
         // Report error etc...
    }
}
```

It looks like something's being released out-of-sync. I'm of course, using ARC so it is (in one respect out of my hands). I'm working on the main thread, not any background thread, so am confused as to what it could be.

Can anyone assist with what could be causing this problem, or give pointers as to where to look? At the moment I'm considering going back to xCode 6.2 to see if it rectifies (or rather 'hides' the problem), but this would be a retrograde step and not really solving the problem. I have done code changes since upgrading, but nothing around the core-data area of the app.

Thanks

Comment: Is this crash iOS 8.3 only?

Comment: Thanks but after 36hours of debugging I got to a really obscure issue which I cannot explain why it was connected. Basically a different tableViewController was 'nilling' its fetchedResultsController on ViewWillDisappear and whenever a Save happened on the tableViewController in question, (and I had more rows than viewable on the first tableViewController - weirdly), a crash happened. Goodness knows what or why the FRC on the first VC was nilled when the view disappeared but that caused issues on a save to the global MOC. Enough to say, I'm relieved it's fixed!

Comment: That seems not the real cause since all your code are in main thread. As I asked is your crash on iOS 8.3 only?